# How do I compare these two statistical PDFs to see which is more likely to be bigger than the other?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

The attached image has two PDFs. The red one is $U(0,1)$. The blue one is more likely to be closer to 1 than to 0. Let's call the uniform distribution $A$ and the second distribution $B$. How do I find $P(B>A)$?

[image]

Comment: $P(B>A) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y) dydx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)\times f_Y(y) dydx = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1} 1\times2y\ dydx = \frac{2}{3}$
Is this what you need? I assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @mxdxzxyjzx I understand most of what you wrote, but I am confused how you got the limits in the integral. Specifically, the x to 1 in the inner integral. Also, why is it 2y if the equation of the blue line is y=2x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures from simulation.

At left, points illustrate the joint distribution of A and B. You want the proportion of points above the green diagonal.

At right, the histogram approximates the density function of B-A. You want the proportion of area in the histogram to the right of
the vertical red line.

[image]

Comment: Left picture suggests joint density of A & B is $f(a,b) = 2b,$ for $0 < a,b < 1.$  Then volume under density over lower triangle is volume of cone with base area $1/2$ and altitude $2.$ So volume of cone is $1/3(1/2)(2) = 1/3.$ That leaves volume above upper triangle $= P(B>A) = 1 -1/3=2/3.$ No calculus needed.